# CMD is recognizing PATH variables but VS Code is not

Tags: visual-studio-code, path

I'm having a problem where PATH variables are recognized in CMD but once I try to use them in the VS Code terminal they seem to break. Obviously, I've tried restarting my computer and VS Code but I can't get to bottom of this problem. If anyone has some idea of what's going on I'd greatly appreciate it.

[image: Visual Proof of Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh oh, it seems my problem was a quite silly mistake on my part. I had a different value for the User Setting "terminal.integrated.cwd" which was causing VS Code to completely ignore my windows PATH.
If you're having the same problem, try edit the user preference "terminal.integrated.cwd" to "".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but when I included these paths in the system environment variable:

```
C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

it worked